# Three.js collision detection with different sizes

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

I have made a collision detection. You can place objects at the raycaster/mouse position on a floor. Therefore you need to click on a button 'Add object', then you get a object(helper) that follows the mouse to see if the new object get a collision with another object. When you click on the position you want, the new object will be placed to the world if there is no collision.

The collision detection I have made works perfectly when the object that is already placed in the world has the same size as the helper/new object.

On the next screenshot you can see a big object and a small(red) helper. The color red means that there is a collision. When I move the mouse more to the right it turns green.

Why does my collision detection work only with 2 objects that have the same size and why doesn't it not with different ones?

[image]

Here is my code in the Click event to show the big object:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 300);
var bigobject = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xFBF5D7,
    opacity: 1
}));
bigobject.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
bigobject.position.y = 100;
objects.push(bigobject);
scene.add(bigobject);
```

Here is my code to show the helper when the button 'Add object' is clicked:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 100 );
helper = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, opacity: 1 } ) );
helper.name = 'helper';
scene.add( helper );
```

Here is my code in the MouseMove event to detect the collision:

```
if(scene.getObjectByName( 'helper' )) {
    helper.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point );
    helper.position.y = 25;

    var helperWidth = helper.geometry.parameters.width;
    var helperLength = helper.geometry.parameters.depth;

    var validpositionObject = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {

        var objectWidth = objects[i].geometry.parameters.width;
        var objectLength = objects[i].geometry.parameters.depth;

        // MIN X
        var helperMinX = helper.position.x;
        var objectMinX = objects[i].position.x;

        // MAX X
        var helperMaxX = helperWidth + helper.position.x;
        var objectMaxX = objectWidth + objects[i].position.x;

        // MIN Z
        var helperMinZ = helper.position.z;
        var objectMinZ = objects[i].position.z;

        // MAX Z
        var helperMaxZ = helperLength + helper.position.z;
        var objectMaxZ = objectLength + objects[i].position.z;

        if (objectMinX <= helperMaxX && objectMaxX >= helperMinX && objectMinZ <= helperMaxZ && objectMaxZ >= helperMinZ) {
            validpositionObject = false;
        }

    }

    if ( validpositionObject === true ) {
        helper.material.color.setHex( 0x00ff00 );
        validposition = true;
    }else{
        helper.material.color.setHex( 0xff0000 );
        validposition = false;
    }

}
```

What goes wrong with the position when it is a big and a small object.. Can anyone help me in the right direction? Many thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that objects are positioned by center, not top-front-left corner. An x collision can be determined by `abs(o1.x - o2.x) < (o1.w + o2.w)/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
function collisonXZ(o1, o2) {
  if (Math.abs(o1.position.x - o2.position.x) > (o1.geometry.parameters.width + o2.geometry.parameters.width) / 2)
    return false;
  if (Math.abs(o1.position.z - o2.position.z) > (o1.geometry.parameters.depth + o2.geometry.parameters.depth) / 2)
    return false;
  return true;
}

var validpositionObject = true;
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
  if (collisionXZ(helper, objects[i])) {
    validpositionObject = false;
    break;
  }
}
```